# Translate Speech to text

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to trans a speech to another language but when i trans a long work it didnt work anymore. I tried assigning it to a string variable and it did true but when i say this word to my mic it didnt work again

```
import speech_recognition
import speech_recognition as sr

from translate import translator
from googletrans import Translator

ear=speech_recognition.Recognizer()
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
print("Listen...")
audio = ear.record(mic, duration=3)
try:
you = ear.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
print(you)
sentence=you
trans=Translator()
translated_sentence=trans.translate(sentence,src='en',dest='vi')
print(translated_sentence.text)
except:
print("i don't know what is it")
```

Can anyone help ? ;( sry my english just bad

Comment: Maybe it's because the indentation is wrong?

Comment: no it's not stackoverflow make it like this